# Azure k8s worknode/master node with redhat OS

Tags: azure, kubernetes

Is there a way to create a AKS with redhat OS master node and work nodes?
It seems the only option is Ubuntu for linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is none. only ubuntu is supported. I think even AKS engine dropped support for everything except for that.